# Google maps right click event error

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a right click event to the google maps.
I get the following error with my code:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '_*e3*': object is null or undefined.
I am not sure what to change.

```
var map;


var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapsGoogle'),
      mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
      HomeTestMarker();

}

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event ) {
         var lat = event.latLng.lat();
         var lng = event.latLng.lng();
        alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LatLng object actually has a lat and lng *function* not property.

Example:
**latLng.lat();**

So your could should actually be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event ) {
     var lat = event.latLng.lat();
     var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
});
```

**Edit**
Here's a working jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/7rZRv/

Comment: Rafael, I used as you said: var lat = event.latLng.lat(); I am not getting any error but i do not see any alert with latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hi netten, that's odd, can you provide the source code so I can take a look? Also check my edited answer above, I've added a working jsFiddle with the rightclick event with a lat/lng alert to better illustrate it (http://jsfiddle.net/7rZRv/)

Comment: Rafael, i edited my code to show the initialize method. I have several other methods for directions, setting markers etc on this same page. I did not copy that part here. Another thing i observed, with the code unchanged i am getting that Microsoft JScript runtime error in internet explorer and not on google chrome. I do not see any alerts as of now.

Comment: placing google.maps.event.addListener within initialze() function worked for me.